# Brute-force equation solving

Tags: c++, brute-force

I'm  writing a program that uses brute-force to solve an equation. Unfortunately, I seem to have an error in my code somewhere, as my program stops at `search = 0.19999`. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

#define min -4.0
#define max 6.5

using namespace std;

double fx (double x){
    long double result = cos(2*x)-0.4*x;
    double scale = 0.00001;
    double value = (int)(result / scale) * scale;
    return value;
}

int sign (double a){
    if(a<0) return -1;
    if(a==0) return 0;
    else return 1;
}

int main(){
vector <double> results;
double step, interval, start, end, search; 
interval=(fabs(min)+fabs(max))/50;
step=0.00001; 

start=min;
end=min+interval;
search=start;

while(end <= max){
    if(sign(start) != sign(end)){
        search=start;
        while(search < end){
            if(fx(search) == 0) results.push_back(search);
            search=search+step;
        }
    }
    start=end;
    end=start + interval;
}

for(int i=0; i<results.size(); i++){
    cout << results[i] << endl;
}
}
```

I've been looking at it for quite some time now and I still can't find the error in the code.
The program should check if there is a root in each given interval and, if yes, check every possibility in that interval. If it finds a root, it should push it into the results vector.

Comment: Did you use the debugger? What are values of `search`? I suppose that this variable at some point no longer changes the value at `search=search+step;`.

Comment: The starting value of `search` is -4.0. It should change to the starting value of each subinterval. The when I track the `search` value, it doesn't even take the value of -4.0 at the beggining, but -0.01 instead.

Comment: `if(sign(start) != sign(end)){` what's that for?

Comment: Like I stated in the answer, it was supposed to check if the values of f(x) for the ends of subintervals have different values to determine if there is a root in it.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already found the answer but I just spotted a problem while trying to find the bug. On line 37 you make the following comparison:

```
if(fx(search) == 0)
```

Since your `fx` function returns `double`. It's generally not advisable to test using the equal operator when dealing with double precision float numbers. Your result will probably never be *exactly* 0, then this test will never return true. I think you should use comparison using a maximum error margin, like this:

```
double maximum_error = 0.005;
if(abs(fx(search)) < maximum_error)
```

I think that would do the trick in your case. You may find more information on [this link](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm)

Even if it's working right now, micro changes in your input numbers, CPU architecture or even compiler flags may break your program. It's highly dangerous to compare doubles in C++ like that, even though it's legal to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a run through the code again and found the error.

`if(sign(start) != sign(end))`
was the culprit. There will be a root if the values of f(x) for `start` and `end` have different signs. Instead, I wrote that the if the signs of `start` and `end` are different, there will be a root. Sorry for the fuss.